# Problema de imagenes Django (no se ven, solo sale la ruta)

Tags: python, django

Puedo subir mis imagenes desde el panel de administrador sin problema alguno pero no logro hacer que la imagen se vea en el html solo aparece la ruta y el nombre del archivo, adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Configuré el media en el settings.py, de la siguiente manera:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

en mi archivo html tengo:

```
<img src="/{{ post.image.url }}" alt="{{ post.title }}">
```

en urls:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta cambiar la plantilla `img` a :

```
<img src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="{{ post.title }}">
```

Quitando el `slash` / antes de `{{ post.image.url }}`

Comment: Perfecto, gracias